# Trace where apache is serving a page from

Tags: apache-2.2

My local server was working fine at http://localhost/ - serving a Wordpress installation.

Then all of a sudden, it switched to a completely unknown page that looks exactly like this one:  http://www.muddyboots.se/

Bizarre!

I've checked that Apache's conf/httpd file has the right home directory:
DocumentRoot "C:/Documents and Settings/myname/My Documents/Website"

I've checked that the .htaccess file in that directory is blank.

I've checked that index.php is the normal index.php for Wordpress.

What is going on?  How can I find out where Apache is serving this mystery page from, and how do I get my Wordpress page back?

Comment: Have you checked your hosts file.  Maybe localhost is pointing somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow a new index.html page was added to my web root, and Apache served index.html (the weird new page) before index.php (the Wordpress page).

Deleted index.html, and good to go.

Answer (score 1):

how about you look into the log files for the page ?
perhaps there is a rewrite rule etc.

Comment: Good idea and something I hadn't tried, but didn't really work - Apache access and error logs report nothing interesting - 404's when I request a page that doesn't exist; 304's when asking for root localhost

Comment: check all the virtual hosts you have - look for RewriteRules - then search for all .htaccess and look for the same. also look for Redirect directives.